# IDA assembly patching fails with "cannot reach destination from current location"

Tags: patch, disassembly, ida

I'm a newbie in IDA (and reverse engineering).

I'm trying to use the "patch->assembly" option in the edit->patch menu, but it fails with an error I cannot understand.

My current line is "jnz short func" (where func is a label I renamed from loc_xxxx), and I am trying to change it to "jmp short func", but when I click OK I get a message box with the message: "cannot reach destination from current location".

Can anyone explain What does that mean and why doesn't it work? I tried to search all over and I can't find any answer!

I must also add that I'm doing this as part of an IDA tutorial I found (in tut4you.com).

Thanks again for your help, I'm really stuck with that!

Comment: Are you using the same target in both cases? - jump short has a range of -128 - 127 from current IP.

Answer (score 0):

"jnz short func" and "jmp short func" instructions doesn't have the same number of bytes..Try to keep code alignment with the original code..
Also jnz, jz, ja,..(conditional jumps) don't work with far pointers (i.e. intersegment).. but only jmp..